# Check if 'Restrict background data' is active on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

There are settings in Data Sense 'Restrict background data' and 'Restrict background data when roamind'. They are blocking background tasks without any notification to application. How to check their state from the app, so I can alert user?

Answer (score 0):

I think that exception message is the only way to detect it. Like in the [background task sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx).

```
    // Place the call to Add in a try block in case the user has disabled agents.
    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Add( task );
    }
    catch ( InvalidOperationException exception )
    {
        if ( exception.Message.Contains( "BNS Error: The action is disabled" ) )
        {
           // Background agents for this application have been disabled by the user.
        }
        if ( exception.Message.Contains( "BNS Error: The maximum number of ScheduledActions of this type have already been added." ) )
        {

        }
        //...
    }
```